# how to combine multiple row in same table into 1 row with different column in sql join with laravel query builder

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-4, query-builder

Good day, (sorry for confusing title, its just hard to express :) )

I have a transactions table with the following field:

```
Transactions TABLE
ID | amount | branch_id | supplier_id 
1  | 1,200  |    2      |  1
```

---

```
Subsidiary TABLE
ID  | Name      | Type
1   | supplier1 | 0
2   | branch_2  | 1
```

---

now I want to display this in my view with the id value properly so I joined the following table (im using laravel query builder)

```
$transactions = DB::table('transactions_table')
->leftJoin('subsidiary_table','transactions_table.supplier_id','=','subsidiary_table.id')
->get(array('transactions_table.id',
'transactions_table.amount',
'subsidiary_table.name as branch',
'subsidiary_table.name as supplier'));
```

Im confused on how can i get this result

```
Display View
ID  |   Ammount  |  Supplier  | Branch 
1   |   1,200    |  Supplier1 | branch_2
```

thanks for clarifying..

Comment: some help anyone? :)

Comment: You want the result in an sql view....? Have you created the migration for view....?

Comment: Hi @hhsadiq  have created my view already.. sorry for vague question but I just want to have the results in array/object so I can render it using my loop.

Comment: Can you share me the code where you created the view....? If your view is working fine, you just need to access this view as any normal modal. I mean you will be doing `Display::all()` and you will have an array of eloquent objects. But i think your views are not properly set yet...

Answer (score 0):

**Create Migration for View**

There is no direct way of creating the sql views using Eloquent/QueryBuilder methods of Laravel. You need to create a migration where you run the normal `CREATE VIEW` command of MySql.

As discussed on [Laravel.io thread](http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?pid=51692)

> Since there are no methods that use the database drivers to create
>   views, you could just create it using SQL syntax.
>
> MySQL example:
>
> DB::statement('CREATE VIEW example_view_name AS SELECT field1, field2
>   FROM table WHERE field1 > field2');

You need to run this code in migration in `up()`

```
public function up()
{
   //db statement for creating view
}
```

**SQL Query**

Your SQL query generation problem is answered on [dba.stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106013/how-to-combine-multiple-row-in-same-table-into-1-row-with-different-column-in-sq)

> ```
>   SELECT  t.ID,  t.amount,  s.Name as Supplier,  sb.Name as Branch FROM
>   Transactions as t JOIN Subsidiary as s ON (s.ID=t.supplier_id) JOIN
>   Subsidiary as sb ON (sb.ID=t.branch_id) WHERE t.ID = 1; Try it.
> ```
>
> PD: You can change the JOIN syntax for  LEFT JOIN if you want to
>   return the t.ID = 1 record from Transactions even if one column don't
>   match in Subsidiary's JOINs.

**Model for SQL View**

Now you have to create the model as if you create for any db table. Then take the privilege of Eloqeunt

`Display::all()`

And you have the collection of eloquent objects.